# Android: Parcelable with inheritance

Tags: java, android, inheritance, parcelable

Now, I have three class, the base class is `BaseWidget` which implements `Parcelable`, two subclasses are `SelectWidget` and `TextWidget`. Then, I use a class named `WidgetInfo` (also implements `Parcelable`) to keep a list of `BaseWidget` or `SelectWidget` or `TextWidget` objects.

While I put `WidgetInfo` object into an `Intent` to start `TestActivity`, and I received `WidgetInfo` in `TestActivity` ,but all the elements of list (which in `WidgetInfo`) convert to `BaseWidget` object. And subclass object member variable is lost. What is problem???

BaseWidget.java:

```
public class BaseWidget implements Parcelable{
    private String name;
    public BaseWidget() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected BaseWidget(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<BaseWidget> CREATOR = new Creator<BaseWidget>() {
        @Override
        public BaseWidget createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BaseWidget(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BaseWidget[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BaseWidget[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
    }
}
```

TextWidget.java:

```
public class TextWidget extends BaseWidget{
    private String width = "100";

    public TextWidget() {
    }

    public String getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(String width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    protected TextWidget(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        width = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeString(width);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<TextWidget> CREATOR = new Creator<TextWidget>() {
        @Override
        public TextWidget createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TextWidget(in);
        }

        @Override
        public TextWidget[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TextWidget[size];
        }
    };
}
```

SelectWidget.java:

```
public class SelectWidget extends BaseWidget{
    private int height = 200;

    public SelectWidget() {
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    protected SelectWidget(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        height = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
        dest.writeInt(height);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<SelectWidget> CREATOR = new Creator<SelectWidget>() {
        @Override
        public SelectWidget createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SelectWidget(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SelectWidget[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SelectWidget[size];
        }
    };
}
```

WidgetInfo.java:

```
public class WidgetInfo implements Parcelable{
    private List<BaseWidget> widgetList;

    public WidgetInfo() {
    }

    public List<BaseWidget> getWidgetList() {
        return widgetList;
    }

    public void setWidgetList(List<BaseWidget> widgetList) {
        this.widgetList = widgetList;
    }

    protected WidgetInfo(Parcel in) {
        widgetList = in.createTypedArrayList(BaseWidget.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<WidgetInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<WidgetInfo>() {
        @Override
        public WidgetInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new WidgetInfo(in);
        }

        @Override
        public WidgetInfo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new WidgetInfo[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeTypedList(widgetList);
    }
}
```

start Intent:

```
    WidgetInfo info = new WidgetInfo();

    BaseWidget widget1 = new BaseWidget();
    BaseWidget widget2 = new TextWidget();
    BaseWidget widget3 = new SelectWidget();

    List<BaseWidget> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(widget1);
    list.add(widget2);
    list.add(widget3);

    info.setWidgetList(list);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("widgetInfo", info);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Try and check the `TextView.SavedState` class, It is a great example of dealing with `Parcelable` and inheritance. Maybe it can help you solve your problem

Comment: why do you think *And subclass object member variable is lost*  ?

Comment: @Blackbelt because,after pass by intent  widget1,widget2,widget3 are convert to BaseWidget object, not subclass object anymore